# KSH Shell script - Process file by blocks of lines

Tags: bash, shell, loops, ksh, tail

I am trying to write a bash script in a KSH environment that would iterate through a source text file and process it by blocks of lines

So far I have come up with this code, although it seems to go indefinitely since the tail command does not return 0 lines if asked to retrieve lines beyond those in the source text file

```
i=1
while [[ `wc -l /path/to/block.file | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'` -gt $((i * 1000)) ]]

do
  lc=$((i * 1000))
  DA=ProcessingResult_$i.csv
  head -$lc /path/to/source.file | tail -1000 > /path/to/block.file
  cd /path/to/processing/batch
  ./process.sh #This will process /path/to/block.file
  mv /output/directory/ProcessingResult.csv /output/directory/$DA
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Before launching the above script I perform a manual 'first injection': `head -$lc /path/to/source.file | tail -1000 > /path/to/temp.source.file`

Any idea on how to get the script to stop after processing the last lines from the source file?

Thanks in advance to you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to create so many temporary files up front before beginning to process each block, you could try the below solution. It can save lot of space when processing huge files.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

range=$1
file=$2

b=0; e=0; seq=1
while true
do
   b=$((e+1)); e=$((range*seq));

   sed -n ${b},${e}p $file > ${file}.temp

   [ $(wc -l ${file}.temp | cut -d " " -f 1) -eq 0 ] && break

   ## process the ${file}.temp as per your need ##

   ((seq++))
done
```

The above code generates only one temporary file at a time. 
You could pass the range(block size) and the filename as command line args to the script.

```
example: extractblock.sh 1000 inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Abis, I'll try that next time I need to perform the processing

Comment: I have used the script for another processing and it worked perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

have a look to `man split`

```
NAME
   split - split a file into pieces

SYNOPSIS
   split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]

   -l, --lines=NUMBER
          put NUMBER lines per output file
```

For example

```
split -l 1000 source.file
```

Or to extract the 3rd chunk for example (1000 here is not the number of lines , it is the number of chunks, or a chunk is 1/1000 of source.file)

```
split -nl/3/1000 source.file
```

A note on condition :

```
[[ `wc -l /path/to/block.file | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'` -gt $((i * 1000)) ]]
```

Maybe it should be source.file instead of block.file, and it is quite inefficient on a big file because it will read (count the lines of the file) for each iteration ; number of lines can be stored in a variable, also using wc on standard input prevents from using awk:

```
nb_lines=$(wc -l </path/to/source.file )
```

Comment: Thanks Nahuel I will try the split command to then iterate the processing script on the resulting files
I'd +1 but I don't have enough privileges so far...

Answer (score 0):

With Nahuel's recommendation I was able to build the script like this:

```
i=1
cd /path/to/sourcefile/
split source.file -l 1000 SF

for sf in /path/to/sourcefile/SF*
do
  DA=ProcessingResult_$i.csv
  cd /path/to/sourcefile/
  cat $sf > /path/to/block.file
  rm $sf
  cd /path/to/processing/batch
  ./process.sh #This will process /path/to/block.file
  mv /output/directory/ProcessingResult.csv /output/directory/$DA
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

This worked great